# Displaying and hiding textview in widget using checkboxes in configuration activity

Tags: android, checkbox, widget, textview

I'm a noob and struggling with something that should be relatively simple.

I have created a widget with 8 TextViews which are populated by a config Activity with Text Fields when the Widget is initialized. All of that is working fine, but I want the user to be able to further customize the widget when it is initialized.

I've placed a checkbox next to each Text field which will be used to make each field either visible (checked), or hidden (unchecked), but I'm stumped as to how to have these checkboxes set the textviews to visible or hidden in the widget class.

Config Layout XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvwelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvinstructions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvwelcome"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_info"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bwidgetconfig"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_finishbutton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etemail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bwidgetconfig"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etphone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_emailhint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etphone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etemail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cbPhone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_phonehint"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etaddress4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etphone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etaddress3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_address4hint"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etaddress3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etaddress2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_address3hint"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etaddress2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etaddress1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_address2hint"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etaddress1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etname"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_address1hint"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:maxHeight="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cbName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_namehint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxHeight="10dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etcontext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/widget_config_contexthint"
        android:maxHeight="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etcontext"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbAddress1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etaddress1"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbAddress2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cbAddress1"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbAddress3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etaddress4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cbAddress2"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbAddress4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etphone"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cbAddress3"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etemail"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etphone"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etemail"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etemail"
        android:text="@string/widget_config_checkbox"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Widget Configuration Class:

```
package com.###.###;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText infocontext;
    EditText infoname;
    EditText infoaddress1;
    EditText infoaddress2;
    EditText infoaddress3;
    EditText infoaddress4;
    EditText infophone;
    EditText infoemail;
    AppWidgetManager awm;
    Context c;
    int awID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        c = WidgetConfig.this;
        infocontext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcontext);
        infoname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
        infoaddress1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress1);
        infoaddress2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress2);
        infoaddress3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress3);
        infoaddress4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress4);
        infophone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etphone);
        infoemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        //Getting info about the widget that launched this Activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if (extras !=null){
            awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
            );  
        }else{
            finish();
        }
        awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String str_context = infocontext.getText().toString();
        String str_name = infoname.getText().toString();
        String str_address1 = infoaddress1.getText().toString();
        String str_address2 = infoaddress2.getText().toString();
        String str_address3 = infoaddress3.getText().toString();
        String str_address4 = infoaddress4.getText().toString();
        String str_phone = infophone.getText().toString();
        String str_email = infoemail.getText().toString();

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvContext, str_context);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvName, str_name);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress1, str_address1);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress2, str_address2);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress3, str_address3);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress4, str_address4);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPhone, str_phone);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvEmail, str_email);

        awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();

    }

}
```

Widget Class:
    package com.###.###;

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            int awID = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Widget deleted from Homescreen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Any help with how to use the checkboxes to hide/show the textviews would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use `yourTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `yourTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I tie that in with the checkboxes in my layout?

Comment: use 2 list, one for `checkBox` and one for `TextView` then when you clicked on `checkBox` you get the position of that and make visibility of `textView` in that position to hidden or anything

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of checkboxes and list of the textviews and when the check box is clicked you can get its location in the list then use textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) , or View.GONE.Don't use View.INVISIBLE.

You can set the tag of each check box with its position as you will use getTag later to know the index of the check box